# terraform plan is giving the error : function call (function yamldecode)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, terraform

Please find the GitLab repo for the terraform scripts which we are using.
[enter link description here](https://gitlab.com/komati.udaykiran/gkewithterraform)
Run in terraform plan gives the below error in an all-in-one.YAML file for the elastic search.

```
Error: Error in function call
 on kubernetes.tf line 49, in locals:
 49:   resource_list = yamldecode(file("${path. module}/all-in-one.yaml")).items
   |----------------
   | path.module is "."

Call to function `"yamldecode"` failed: on line 458, column 1: unexpected extra
content after value.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7sAy.png)

Comment: there probably shouldn't be a space between `path.` and `module` on line 29 of your code

Comment: Hi Patrick, we tried without spaces and space as well but still the same error.

Comment: Please don't use images for code snippets, as it is incredibly hard to read and not indexed for searching. It's explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 4):

As is describe in [the fine manual](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/yamldecode.html):

> Only one YAML document is permitted. If multiple documents are present in the given string then this function will return an error.

and one can trivially reproduce your error message:

```
  content  = yamldecode("---\nhello: world\n---\ntoo: bad\n")
```

```
  on main.tf line 14, in resource "local_file" "example":
  14:   content  = yamldecode("---\nhello: world\n---\ntoo: bad\n")

Call to function "yamldecode" failed: on line 2, column 1: unexpected extra
content after value.
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,I have tried splitting this all-in-one.yaml file( https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.2.0/all-in-one.yaml ) and got the error.

Comment: Error: apmservers.apm.k8s.elastic.co failed to create kubernetes rest client for update of resource: resource [apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/CustomResourceDefinition] isn't valid for cluster, check the APIVersion and Kind fields are valid.

  on kubernetes.tf line 32, in resource "kubectl_manifest" "all-in-one":
  32: resource "kubectl_manifest" "all-in-one" {

Comment: That sounds like a new question, and that new question belongs on https://ServerFault.com because that problem is not about programming